# Looker Report is Owned by Me But I cannot Find It

Tags: looker

I have spent hours creating a really nice multi channel dashboard, and I have shared it with others, but I can't see it in my Looker. When others who have edit right go to the settings, it says that is owned by me however, I can't seem to find it. Is this a bug? By the way, I have lookre studio pro.

I want to be able to see my report.